# json aquired tumblr feed error, uncaught syntaxerror: unexpected token <

Tags: json, api, oauth, tumblr, api-key

This is my first question posted here, so I appologize ahead of time if I use bad form.

I have my tumblr blog posts fed into the aside section of my website. Tonight the feed is not displaying on my page. Chrome shows this error:

```
"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < hearthescene.tumblr.com:1"
```

Here's a snipet of code showing my json request:

```
$.getJSON(
    "http://hearthescene.tumblr.com/api/read/json?callback=?", 
    function(data) { 
        ...formatting the data for my site....
    }
);
```

I haven't actually edited anything on the site in a couple days. I was wondering if tumblr has upped the security and I need to do some OAuth authentication or supply an api key?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to add the api_key as such: 
$.getJSON("http://hearthescene.tumblr.com/api/read/json?/?api_key={my_api_key}&callback=?",